# Would a species of giant ape be able to live in an taiga?

Tags: biology, environment, adaptability

In my world, I plan on having a species (not a race) of giant apes that inhabit an island around the size of Italy. This island is still heavily forested in many places, although the development of civilization as well as a mountain range that nearly splits the island in two disrupts the old-growth forests here. The Giants themselves are around 10 to 12 feet tall and are covered in fur.

Would they even be able to survive in this environment? If so, what adaptations (aside from those to regulate their large size) would be needed to help them in this environment, and what would they rely on for food?

Answer (score 2):

An island the size of Italy may be a little small for these large apes. They remind me of the neanderthal humanoids. And those thrived in northern latitudes during the last ice age. In fact gigantism is one of the adaptations animals may go through to adapt to colder environments. Since it is more efficient to keep a larger body warm than a smaller one.

On what they would eat. That may largely depend on their smarts and how active they are. They can be like panda's. Sluggish most/all of the time and eating plants. Or more like bears eating everything in the summer with an hibernation period. Or like gorilla's quite smart and active all year round. Those will need large prey to hunt in winter/spring and may shift their diet to eat more insects, and high caloric fruits and roots in summer/fall.

Comment: *"Eating plants":* The taiga is not famous for its luxuriant vegetable productivity. The large herbivores living in the taiga, such as the elk (= moose in American) and the reindeer (= caribou in American) are ruminants, and as such have (1) a built-in bioreactor to ferment cellulose; and (2) the heat dissipated by the fermentation process helps with the severe winters.

Comment: "Or like gorilla's quite smart and active all year round" - I'll second AlexP comment here. In taiga, there is not so much to eat during winters, so hibernation may be a better choice.

Comment: all three options are possible where ill acknowledge that hibernation would be the most likely adaptation you would see. i included all three to give an idea of the possibility's. naturally extremes are unlikely to thrive. @Nick T having it act as an ape all year round would require frequent and efficient catches of large animals.

Answer (score 1):

yes yes.  Kodiak bears.  Pandas.  Elephant seals.  how droll, how droll.

I propose as your model

**LEAFCUTTER ANTS!**

[image: leafcutter ants]

https://www.treehugger.com/crazy-facts-leaf-cutter-ants-4864484

Your Sasquatches have huge underground cavern complexes beneath the forest. The provenance of these caverns is another matter but now they are occupied by the apes, and the ten thousand year old fungoid god they tend.  The apes bring down plant material from the forest and the sea and are rewarded by sweet fungus food from the ancient growth filling the tunnels.  The fungus also feeds the roots of the trees in a commensal exchange.  The island, trees, apes, and fungus are a superorganism.

Sometimes the humans on the island can smell the fungus, and they wonder what it is.